# Is it possible to embed C++ widget to PyQt application?

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application and most widgets written in Python. I want to write some widget in C++ Qt to make it faster and then embed it into my PyQt QMainWindow.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use SIP to be able to execute a widget created in C ++ from python, in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/Qt5toPyQt5) I show an example of how to do it.

The structure of the example is as follows:

```
├── configure.py
├── sip
│   ├── AnalogClock.sip
│   └── PyAnalogClock.sip
└── src
    ├── analogclock.cpp
    ├── analogclock.h
    ├── analogclockl_global.h
    └── AnalogClock.pro
```

In the src folder you must create the widget library

In the sip folder you must place the structure of the class that you will expose:

**AnalogClock.sip**

```
%Import QtGui/QtGuimod.sip
%Import QtWidgets/QtWidgetsmod.sip

%If (Qt_5_0_0 -)

class AnalogClock : public QWidget{

%TypeHeaderCode
#include "analogclock.h"
%End

public:
    AnalogClock(QWidget *parent /TransferThis/ = 0);

protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e); 
};

%End
```

**PyAnalogClock.sip**

```
%Module(name=PyAnalogClock, call_super_init=True, keyword_arguments="Optional")
%DefaultMetatype PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType
%DefaultSupertype sip.simplewrapper
%Include AnalogClock.sip
```

`configure.py` is the script that configures the compilation of the project, if you have any problems you must modify some path (it has been tested in Linux)

It is then compiled by executing the following:

```
python configure.py
make 
sudo make install
```

When executing the previous one it generates a folder called modules, inside of it is the dynamic library, in the case of the example `PyAnalogClock.so`, this file we place it in the folder of the source code:

```
.
├── main.py
└── PyAnalogClock.so
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyAnalogClock import AnalogClock

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys

    a=QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=AnalogClock()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to build it, but it fails. python3 configure.py passes, but `make` step says that it cannot find library MyLabel

Comment: I've reloaded the project. Now `make` step passes, but when I try to run `Examples.main.py`, it gives an error: ImportError: libMyLabel.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Great, it works. I'll try to build it under Windows (with nmake).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Since you posted it, SIP has undergone some changes and the newest version does not seem to work with your code anymore. Have you planned any update to your repository?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SIP](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) to create bindings for your `C++` code the same way that the `PyQt` bindings are made.

However, the bindings generated by SIP are themselves `C++` code, and in the case of `PyQt` link directly into the `Qt` binaries. If you just intend to rewrite `PyQt` code as `C++` then any speedup realised will be negligible, as very little native python is executed in the first place.