# PyQT5 and C++ in the same project

Tags: pyqt

Is possible to use pyqt5 for some logic written in Python, and at the same time, use some C++ code for other actions in a GUI? Or are you locked using only PYQT, since the C++ code is ignored, when the PYQT code is running?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to embed C++ widget to PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258808/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-widget-to-pyqt-application)

Comment: I would like to write most of the code in pyqt, but if I have the need to put in some C++ code in a button for example; and have a separate function just in C++, I can do that.

I do not believe that this is the same as the question mentioned @hyde; I don't want to embed a widget, but write code in both languages in the same form for example

Comment: First of all you will never be able to call C++ directly, but rather a C++ binary because C++ is a compiled language, unlike python it does not have an interpreter. So if you want to do it you have 2 options: generate an executable and call it with QProcess or similars

Comment: (cont.) , or you will have to convert your code with the help of a library like SWING or SIP (like PyQt5 does it) to a library (.dll,. so, .a). What advantages would it have? For me it would not have much advantage since currently the standard functions and specialization libraries in processing are written in C or C++ such as numpy, scipy, etc. For me the opposite would have more disadvantages since the conversion of C++ to a python library will have to learn new functions, in addition to a time of further development.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am aware of that; been writing C++ for more than a decade now :) I meant that I want to use C++ code for certain actions performed by buttons or sliders for example, or use C++ code for functions that perform backend tasks, but still get triggered by elements on the QT UI. My PyQT project is loading a QT designer file, and since I already have C++ code that I used outside QT (which is new to me), I was wondering if the 2 could co-exist in the same project and files. From what I can read, it seems that it can't be done in the way that I was planning to. thanks!

Comment: Ideally I was hoping that I can mix and match; so I don't have to convert the C++ code used for non-UI actions, into PyQT code necessarily; but at this point seems to be more of a hassle than an advantage; I can convert the C++ code to Python and just go for PyQT. Thanks