# How to embed a C++ widget into PyQt5?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, sip

This relates to [Is it possible to embed C++ widget to PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258808/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-widget-to-pyqt-application).

This is basically the same question, only that the newer versions of SIP have changed their configuration method so the great example given in the original question is deprecated now.

I am looking for a minimal example that works with the current version of SIP 6 and explicitly works with Qt.

There is a minimum example for general bindings at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/examples.html#a-standalone-project, but I am stuck at making the leap to actually bind C++ code that contains Qt.